# Second echo not working

Tags: php, select, echo

I am making a form using a mixture of SQL and PHP. the first select object is echo'ing fine but the second will not show what so ever?

Can anybody give me any ideas?

Code is:

```
  <form method="post">

    <label for="RL">Rail Length: </label>
    <select id="RL">
    <option>----</option>
    <?
    foreach ($liftsecond as $lifts){
echo '<option>'.$lifts["Rail Length"].'</option>';} ?>

    <label for="RL">Stair Hand: </label>
    <select id="RL">
    <option>----</option>
    <?
    foreach ($liftsecond as $side){
echo '<option>'.$side["Stair Hand"].'</option>';}   
?>
```

(there is form tags around this but have not shown here)

Comment: Show your SQL and how you're getting the data

Comment: Here is my Sql<? 
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liftquote;port=8889","root","root");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "Could not connect to the database.";
 exit;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your code where you closed the first or second select tags with closing tags. If you forgot to do that, it could be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your php is correct. Simply do a var_dump($liftsecond); to be sure there is an index 'Stair Hand'. 
I assume $liftsecond is data from your SQL DB so if this is the case, it would be a good idea to first check if is_array($liftsecond), otherwise you could get an error if there are no results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: dumped and it shows 'Stair Hand' as index. still no luck.